# How to avoid geb waitFor{} or minimize the waitFor{} in the codebase?

Tags: groovy, geb

We use Backbone.js as our UI framework and for automation, we use geb with gradle. However, when we try to automate anything, mostly without writing waitFor{} statement, test fails. It's kind of frustrating that you need to use so many waitFor{} in your test. I believe there should be some better ways to do that. Any help/suggestion would be highly beneficial to get rid from this thing!

Comment: If I don't wait for the page to load, then how will I interact with the page? I am asking for a solution why do we need to hardcode that waitFor{}!

Comment: Are you using waitFor to wait for AJAX calls/other asynchronous tasks? Can you post a small example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using frameworks like Backbone.js or Angular for building single page apps results in very asynchronous web applications. Retrieving data in an async way by means of AJAX requests and then using it to change parts of the page is different from synchronously (re)loading a page and is not detected by WebDriver.

Because everything is essentially async in such apps you will have to deal with many `waitFor {}` in your Geb tests, there's no way I know of around it. You will also have to keep in mind which parts and actions are async in your app and if you don't and forget to put a `waitFor {}` where it's necessary you will end up with flakey tests. There is no silver bullet here.

One thing you can do is to "hide" the asynchronicity in your pages and modules. Don't interact with asynchronous elements directly but wrap such interactions in page and module methods. This way your tests will be easier to read and you will not have to duplicate all these `waitFor {}` blocks all over the place which should also make it harder to forget to put one where it's required.

Comment: Perfect @erdi! That's what I experienced too! Thanks for the details explanation :)

Comment: An `atCheckWaiting` configuration directive in your `GebConfig.groovy` file may help to reduce the number of `waitFor` commands that must be hidden: http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.10.0/configuration.html#waiting_in_at_checkers